# Needed text and button on images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a web app and I want the output to be something like this -
[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row wrapper">
    <img class="col" style="display: inline-block;
                    width: 25%; -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
                    filter:brightness(20%);" src="Assets/imgs1.jpg" alt="?">

    <img class="col" style="display: inline-block;
                    width: 25%; -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
                    filter:brightness(20%);" src="Assets/imgs2.jpg" alt="?">

    <img class="col" style="display: inline-block;
                    width: 25%; -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
                    filter:brightness(20%);" src="Assets/imgs3.jpg" alt="?">

    <img class="col" style="display: inline-block;
                    width: 25%; -webkit-filter: brightness(20%);
                    filter:brightness(20%);" src="Assets/imgs4.jpg" alt="?">
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have achieved this

[image]

I am not able to add text on my images

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: Put the images as background of the `div` would be the first step...

Comment: @Roy I tried that images go below each other

Comment: @NightyKnight give position to your text and button. and give position `relative` to your main class
 `for eg :-  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;`

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen images treated as layout grid columns. I don't believe it's a good idea, either. Put your images _inside_ your layout grid, or apply them as backgrounds.

Comment: Make a grid of flexbox type layout , use div blocks and give them background as images.

Comment: Also, use a class for your repeated styles. Don't junk up your HTML with that.

Comment: @NightyKnight always try to use external CSS, don't use inline CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one strategy which uses the `:after` pseudo-element to veil the images like you were apparently trying to do.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-img {
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  margin-left: -15px;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 wrapper">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 wrapper">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 wrapper">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="?">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 wrapper">
      <img class="col-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" alt="?">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```